# how to add images getting from server to google map android as a marker?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, marker

[image]Please suggest me,

I am getting url of images and need to place in google map as marker

```
for(AtmInfo info :atmInfoList){
    //latitude   = Double.parseDouble(pub.getLatitude()) ;
    // longitude  =   Double.parseDouble(getIntent().getStringExtra("lon"));
    Marker source = mMap.addMarker(
                   new MarkerOptions()
        .position( 
            new LatLng(
                Double.parseDouble(info.getLatitude()), 
                Double.parseDouble(info.getLongitude())))
        .title(info.getBankName())
        .snippet(info.getBankAddress())    
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_green)));
}
mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindowAdapter());
```

Comment: instead of R.drawable.marker_green ,i have to set image url from server, how to do this?

Comment: you probably needs to download the image to a bitmap and then https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/BitmapDescriptorFactory.html#fromBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)

Comment: i needed to display like my uploaded image..

Comment: i have posted complete solution have a look on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the complete solution. 
create Marker like this

```
Marker source = mMap.addMarker(
                   new MarkerOptions()
        .position( 
            new LatLng(
                Double.parseDouble(info.getLatitude()), 
                Double.parseDouble(info.getLongitude())))
        .title(info.getBankName())
        .snippet(info.getBankAddress())    
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(getBitmap(url,this)))); //call getbitmap() method to download image from url
```

Download bitmap from url

add method getBitmap and decode method in your project(for ex. util class or common function)

```
public static Bitmap getBitmap(String url,Context context) 
    {
        FileCache fileCache=new FileCache(context);
        MemoryCache memoryCache=new MemoryCache();
        File f=fileCache.getFile(url);
        //from SD cache
        //CHECK : if trying to decode file which not exist in cache return null
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if(b!=null)
            return b;
        // Download image file from web
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap=null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
            // Constructs a new FileOutputStream that writes to file
            // if file not exist then it will create file
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            // See Utils class CopyStream method
            // It will each pixel from input stream and
            // write pixels to output stream (file)
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            conn.disconnect();
            //Now file created and going to resize file with defined height
            // Decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
            b = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;

        } catch (Throwable ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            if(ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError)
                memoryCache.clear();
            return null;
        }
    }

    //Decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private static Bitmap decodeFile(File f){

        try {
            //Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            FileInputStream stream1=new FileInputStream(f);
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream1,null,o);
            stream1.close();
            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            // Set width/height of recreated image
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE=85;
            int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
            int scale=1;
            while(true){
                if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp/=2;
                height_tmp/=2;
                scale*=2;
            }

            //decode with current scale values
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
            FileInputStream stream2=new FileInputStream(f);
            Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream2, null, o2);
            stream2.close();
            return bitmap;

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, get the image from URL.

Secondly, after getting the image you can use overlay for adding custom marker on map.

Comment: i got url from server, can you explain how to set these images on map like marker?

Comment: For custom marker you may refer to this link

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/android-google-maps-tutorial.html